# Не открывается Atom

Tags: windows, atom

Установил новый 1.40.1, открываю, ничего не происходит, висит в диспетчере задач. Пробовал открывать версию из zip, тоже самое, переустанавливал несколько раз. Win10 pro 64bit 1903v.

Comment: Мммм... `vcredist` все стоят?

Comment: Все поставил, перезагрузил, тоже самое

Comment: 64 бита на 64 битной ОС?

Comment: Да, ставил 64 версии

Comment: А если воткнуть виртуалку с чистой 10-кой и поставить туда?

Comment: Блин, мороки много, у меня инет медленный чтобы качать образ. Может еще как можно решить?

Comment: Ну я весной ставил Атом, правда на 7 и всё поехало тока так. Опять же - 10 - это текущая версия, на которой все всё тестят. Я не думаю, что разрабы Атома, который разрабатывается Гитхабом, который принадлежит Майкам не тестили запуск на 10. Я думаю, что ты просто угасил винду или обновления прилетели криво. Именно поэтому предложил попробовать запуск на чистой копии, чтобы исключить фактор "это дебилы в Редмонде\Гитхабе недоковыряли."

Comment: `Медленный = платный\дорогой` или `медленный = долго ждать`?

Comment: Долго ждать, в деревне живу. Это явно не проблема разрабов, на прошлом компе с10кой работало.

Comment: Ну тогда копать почему у тебя прога не запускается - можно очень долго. Дольше, чем выкачать 4+гб десятки и Виртуалбокса. `7c58bd350161fc29596f070c0dc69694be7b7e7e` sha1 свежей десятки.